# Playing mp3/wav in Java

Tags: java, mp3, wav

For a school project we programmed a Pong game in Java. Unfortunately I am not that skilled in the language. In the GamePanel class shown below there is a function "checkCollision", which checks if the ball touches the paddles. I want to play a wav file as sound every time the ball touches a racket. This is stored as "collision_sound.wav" in the project folder. Unfortunately, when I run the program, I get an error message that the specified file is not found.

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    static final int GAME_WIDTH = 1000;
    static final int GAME_HEIGHT = (int) (GAME_WIDTH * (0.5555));
    static final Dimension SCREEN_SIZE = new Dimension(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
    static final int BALL_DIAMETER = 30;
    static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 25;
    static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 90;

    Thread gameThread;
    Image image;
    Image bkImage;
    Graphics graphics;
    Random random;
    Paddle paddle1;
    Paddle paddle2;
    Ball ball;
    Score score;
    private Clip collisionSound;

    GamePanel(int w, int h) {
        newPaddles();
        newBall();
        score = new Score(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new AL());
        this.setPreferredSize(SCREEN_SIZE);
        this.loadBackground("DHBW_Heidenheim.jpg");
        this.loadCollisionSound("collision_sound.wav");

        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    private void loadBackground(String name) {
        System.out.println("Ich spring rein");
        String userpath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        userpath += "\\src\\" + name;
        System.out.println(userpath + " HAHA " + name);
        System.out.println("Spieler 2: ");
        try {
            bkImage = ImageIO.read(new File(userpath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void loadCollisionSound(String filename) {
        System.out.println("Ich spring rein");
        String userpath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        userpath += "\\src\\" + filename;
        System.out.println(userpath + "  " + filename);
        File file = new File (userpath);
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            collisionSound = AudioSystem.getClip();
            collisionSound.open(audioInputStream);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void playCollisionSound() {
        if (collisionSound.isRunning()) { //id == 1 bedeutet Spieler 1, ansonsten Spieler 2 
            System.out.println("es geht unnormal");
            collisionSound.stop();
            collisionSound.setFramePosition(0);
            collisionSound.start();
    }   else {
            collisionSound.start();
            System.out.println("es geht normal");
        }
    }
    public void newBall() {
        random = new Random();
        ball = new Ball((GAME_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2), random.nextInt(GAME_HEIGHT - BALL_DIAMETER),
                BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);
    }

    public void newPaddles() {
        paddle1 = new Paddle(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 1);
        paddle2 = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH, (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 2);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        image = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics = image.getGraphics();
        graphics.drawImage(bkImage, 0, 0, null);
        draw(graphics);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        paddle1.draw(g);
        paddle2.draw(g);
        ball.draw(g);
        score.draw(g);
    }

    public void move() {
        paddle1.move();
        paddle2.move();
        ball.move();
    }

    public void checkCollision() {

        // Ball prallt von den oberen und unteren Fensterrändern ab
        if (ball.y <= 0) {
            ball.setYDirection(-ball.yVelocity); //Ball prallt ab und bewegt sich in entgegengesetzte Richtung 
        }
        if (ball.y >= GAME_HEIGHT - BALL_DIAMETER) {
            ball.setYDirection(-ball.yVelocity);
        }
        //Ball prallt von den Schlägern ab
        //Interaktion des Balls mit Schläger 1 
        if (ball.intersects(paddle1)) {
            ball.xVelocity = Math.abs(ball.xVelocity);
            ball.xVelocity++;
            playCollisionSound();
            if (ball.yVelocity > 0)
                ball.yVelocity++; //Geschwindigkeit wird erhöht
            else
                ball.yVelocity--;
            ball.setXDirection(ball.xVelocity);
            ball.setYDirection(ball.yVelocity);
        }
        
        //Interaktion des Balls mit Schläger 2 
        if (ball.intersects(paddle2)) {
            ball.xVelocity = Math.abs(ball.xVelocity);
            ball.xVelocity++; 
            playCollisionSound();
            if (ball.yVelocity > 0)
                ball.yVelocity++; //Geschwindigkeit wird erhöht
            else
                ball.yVelocity--;
            ball.setXDirection(-ball.xVelocity); 
            ball.setYDirection(ball.yVelocity);
        }
        //Stoppt die Schläger an den Fensterrändern, also wenn diese ganz oben bzw. ganz unten sind 
        if (paddle1.y <= 0) //wenn ganz oben 
            paddle1.y = 0;
        if (paddle1.y >= (GAME_HEIGHT - PADDLE_HEIGHT)) //wenn ganz unten 
            paddle1.y = GAME_HEIGHT - PADDLE_HEIGHT;
        if (paddle2.y <= 0) //wenn ganz oben 
            paddle2.y = 0;
        if (paddle2.y >= (GAME_HEIGHT - PADDLE_HEIGHT)) //wenn ganz unten 
            paddle2.y = GAME_HEIGHT - PADDLE_HEIGHT;
        // Ein Spieler erhält einen Punkt und es werden neue Schläger und ein neuer Ball erzeugt
        if (ball.x <= 0) { //linker Rand wurde berührt
            score.player2++; //Score von Spieler 2 wird erhöht
            newPaddles();
            newBall();
            System.out.println("Spieler 2: " + score.player2);
        }
        if (ball.x >= GAME_WIDTH - BALL_DIAMETER) { //rechter Rand wird berührt
            score.player1++; //Spieler 1 erhält einen Punkt 
            newPaddles();
            newBall();
            System.out.println("Spieler 1: " + score.player1);
        }
    }


    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        while (true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                move();
                checkCollision();
                repaint();
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }

    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            paddle1.keyPressed(e);
            paddle2.keyPressed(e);
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            paddle1.keyReleased(e);
            paddle2.keyReleased(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Already tried a couple of things, but didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Don’t reference ‘src’ in you code, it won’t exist once you export/package your app. Embedded resources can’t be referenced as Files, instead you need to use Class#getResource instead